# Can't use HTML with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've trying to build a basic Flask web app. When I try adding simple html code (like below) to my editor, and then 'Flask run' in Terminal, it gives me "invalid syntax". I've tried a lot of different html code and it doesn't like any of it.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello, world'

<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEcqHA7dbwM">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is completely broken, because that HTML at the end isn't actually valid Python syntax.  The simplest way to do exactly what you're attempting, is to create a python string containing that HTML, then make the `hello_world` function return that string:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    html = """<iframe width="420" height="315"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEcqHA7dbwM">
        </iframe>
    """
    return html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Of course if you created a directory called `templates` and put the HTML in a file at `templates/index.html` you could then use Flask's `render_template` function to achieve the same:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: This is technically correct, but the recommended way now to run Flask apps is to use the `flask` CLI script, instead of `app.run`. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/server/#in-code.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if all you want to do is serve up a static HTML page, you don't really need Flask, since it is intended for dynamic content. Instead, you can put all of your static HTML files in a single directory, and run `python3 -m http.server` to start a simple, lightweight HTTP server that can serve up static HTML content.

```
$ cat <<EOF > index.html
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEcqHA7dbwM">
</iframe>
EOF

$ python3 -m http.server
```

Now you can open `http://localhost:8000` in your browser and see your static content served up.

If you want to use a different port, pass the port number as an argument to the python call: `python3 -m http.server 9999`

If you are running Python 2, the equivalent command is `python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any idea about the code you just written ?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

html = """<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEcqHA7dbwM"></iframe>"""

@app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
    return html
```

then run `flask run` to start Flask server